# Zero size array is not aligned inside a structure

Tags: c, gcc, struct, memory-alignment

I found a strange behaviour regarding the memory alignment of zero sized arrays when declared inside an unpacked structure. It crossed my mind to throw zero sized arrays to label parts of the structure. I don't think it has a particular use but still i had the feeling some interesting code might be produced.

Is this behaviour compiler specific or will all compilers give the same result *(they will not align the zero size array)*?

---

Take the following code for an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct tagOBJ
{
    char Label1[0];
    int A;

    char Label2[0];
    int B;
    int C;
};
typedef struct tagOBJ OBJ;

int main()
{
    OBJ a;
    printf("%d == %d\n", &a.A, a.Label1);
    printf("%d == %d\n", &a.B, a.Label2);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above case, the output is as expected:

```
6422292 == 6422292
6422296 == 6422296
```

However, if i add in another variable to the structure that implies padding, the given addresses are different:

```
struct tagOBJ
{
    char Label1[0];
    int A;
    char D;

    char Label2[0];
    int B;
    int C;
};
typedef struct tagOBJ OBJ;
```

Produces

```
6422288 == 6422288
6422296 == 6422293 // ! false
```

Comment: Zero-size arrays are not allowed in standard C. This whole `#define` obfuscation is not adding clarity to the code either.

Comment: I would recommend against simulating concepts from other languages in C. Generally this leads to poor C code. If you want to program using public and private members, pick C++ or something else.

Comment: Dont know why i named the labels PUBLIC and PRIVATE. Simply popped in my mind as the most obvious split between the variables of a structure. Had no intent to mimic C++ specifiers

Comment: You might use structs within the struct then. Those can be anonymous if desired.

Comment: To avoid UB, please remember that the correct format specifier to print pointers is `"%p"` and the pointer itself should be cast to `void *`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Zero-size arrays are allowed in standard C per C 2018 4 6 and 4 7.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i have read something about zero sized arrays being allowed in the standard only as the last member of the struct (aka flexible array member). However i dont think the standard says anything about zero sized array members being placed between structure members.

Comment: @Tudor: C is not a closed language. Paragraphs 6 and 7 of clause 4 of the C standard says that C implementations may extend the language, and that any extension that does not interfere with the core language still conforms to the C standard. In other words, the C standard does not specify what happens when zero-length arrays are used, but it allows them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this behaviour compiler specific or will all compilers give the same result (they will not align the zero size array)?

Arrays with zero size are not allowed by the C language itself. Your code is invalid and the behavior of your code is ["undefined"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Any compiler can do *anything*, so, well, the answer would be yes, it is compiler specific, and there is also no requirement that the behavior should be anyhow consistent.

Also:

```
printf("%d == %d\n", &a.A, a.Label1);
```

is also invalid. `%d` expects an `int` - `&a.A` is a pointer.

In the spirit of C, would be nicer to add accessor functions:

```
void *OBJ_public(const OBJ *t) { return (void*)&t->A; }
void *OBJ_private(const OBJ *t) { return (void*)&t->C; }
```

If you really want to work with macros, well, you can do this:

```
#define OBJ_PUBLIC   A
#define OBJ_PRIVATE  C

#define PUBLIC(TYPE, VAR)   (void*)(&(VAR).TYPE##_PUBLIC)
#define PRIVATE(TYPE, VAR)  (void*)(&(VAR).TYPE##_PRIVATE)

int main() {
   OBJ a;
   printf("%p\n", PUBLIC(OBJ, a));
}
```

> ```
> 6422296 == 6422293 // ! false
> ```

Gcc has the extension of [zero length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html). And I think - sure it's false. `char` member starts when the last struct member ends, so it "glues up" and points to the next byte right after the previous member - so it points to `(char*)&a.D + 1`, which may or may not be equal to the address of the next member, so it depends on padding. In this case next member is `int`, so there is some padding required between `char` and `int`.